# How to do filters for <span>

Tags: jquery

From Spring to UI I recive this code:

```
 <span th:text="${fromController.number}"/>
```

number - this a double from DB
I want to do filters from 0 to 30, 30-80 and more 80.
I have written this code for filters:

```
<div id="numberSelected">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="number01" value="1"/> 0 -30
                    <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="number02" value="2"/>30 - 80<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="number03" value="3"/>>80
                </div>
```

I don't understand how to hide/show 
I write this code:

```
  $('input').change(function() {
    var category = $(this).val();
    var arrayNumber = [];
    if (category==1){
        arrayNumber = $("[class^=number]");
        for(i=0; i<arrayNumber.length; i++){
            if (0<arrayNumber[i].innerHTML<30){
                $("[class^=number]").show();
            }else {
                $("[class^=number]").hide();
            }
            console.log(arrayNumber[i].innerHTML);
        }
```

In console I see all value from span(s), but hide/show don't work.
Where my misstake?

Comment: you seems to be missing class on span

Comment: I don't understand want you want exactly? What should hide when what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I have given a sample implementation. Please check if that helps!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
            $("#myDiv").html($("#myDiv").html() + "<span class='number'> " + i + " </span>");
        }

        $('[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            var that = this;
            var firstIntervalStart = 0;
            var firstIntervalEnd = 0;
            var secondIntervalStart = 0;
            var secondIntervalEnd = 0;
            
            hideAllSpans();

            var firstCheckBoxChecked = $("#number01").is(':checked');
            var secondCheckBoxChecked = $("#number02").is(':checked');
            var thirdCheckBoxChecked = $("#number03").is(':checked');

            if (firstCheckBoxChecked) {
                firstIntervalStart = 0;
                firstIntervalEnd = 30;
                if (secondCheckBoxChecked) {
                    firstIntervalEnd = 80;
                    if (thirdCheckBoxChecked) {
                        firstIntervalEnd = $(".number").length;
                    }
                }
                else if (thirdCheckBoxChecked) {
                    secondIntervalStart = 80;
                    secondIntervalEnd = $(".number").length;
                }
            }
            else if (secondCheckBoxChecked) {
                firstIntervalStart = 30;
                firstIntervalEnd = 80;
                if (thirdCheckBoxChecked) {
                    firstIntervalEnd = $(".number").length;
                }
            }
            else if (thirdCheckBoxChecked) {
                firstIntervalStart = 80;
                firstIntervalEnd = $(".number").length;
            }

            for (var i = firstIntervalStart; i < firstIntervalEnd; i++) {
                $($(".number")[i]).show();
            }

            if (secondIntervalStart != 0) {
                for (var i = secondIntervalStart; i < secondIntervalEnd; i++) {
                    $($(".number")[i]).show();
                }
            }

        });

        function hideAllSpans() {
            $(".number").hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numberSelected">
        <input type="checkbox" id="number01" value="1"/>0 -30
        <input type="checkbox" id="number02" value="2" />30 - 80<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="number03" value="3" />>80
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the checkbox be replaced by radio buttons..? the functionality u have implemented suggests radio button usage and not checkbox. if it is check box then when someone checks all 3 check boxes they should see all the content which is not the case with the code..

Comment: yes, Ideally radios has to be used. I donot know if the person who posted actual question chose CheckBoxes intentionally!!

Comment: becouse you can choose two checkbox together

Comment: Made changes, plz see if that's what is needed!! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you answer not correct, becouse I recive all my span from Spring with `<span th:text="${fromController.number}"/>`